# Validate variable content against Angular's internal URL pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have a variable inside a controller and I want to validate that it's a URL. I could search a regexp here, in SO, and just use that, but I'd rather use Angular's internal pattern so I could benefit of future updates of that pattern (if any).

Is there a way I can validate a variable against Angular's internal patterns?

EDIT:

Just to be clear, I'm not asking how to validate user input. That is already nicely covered in Angular's docs. I'm asking how to validate a variable that lives in my controller and hasn't been created by user input.

Basically, I'm asking for something like `angular.validateUrl(my_var)`.

Comment: While reading I was thinking it was some newcomer who don't know how to ask a good question. No offense but I was expecting more detailed question and **effort** from a member with 3K rep and so many badges.

PS: I didn't down voted.

Comment: @noob Can't see anything missing in my question. There is no code to show, as I'm asking precisely how to do a one-liner.

Comment: Nothing is missing in the question, yet it's not clear what type of validation you want. Feels like quite simple thing but not clear what exactly.

Comment: @dfsq What part of "URL validation" is not clear? The "URL" or the "validation"? I'm not asking for rocket science here, I'm asking for a straight URL matching/validation function using Angular's internal pattern. I just can't understand what exactly of that is not clear enough.